# "502 Bad Gateway" error in a WordPress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, debian

I've been trying to install WordPress with a LEMP configuration for a localhost connection. I reviewed some answers, but I can't figure out why this error is being displayed.

I've installed Nginx/1.10.3, MySQL 5, and PHP 7.0 in a [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) distribution. I have configured the Nginx configuration files reaching WordPress' folder, and I can't display the installation screen on my browser. I've tried using Firefox and Chrome to display the localhost page.

Here I'm attaching my Nginx (/etc/sites-available/file) configuration file:

```
server{

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/wordpress.example;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;}
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;}

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;}

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;}
}
```

And here I attach my WordPress (/var/www/directory/wp-config.php) file configuration parameters that I modified:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this information from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpressdb' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'wordpressuser' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'root' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', '3.14.164.34');

/** Database character set to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The database collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

I also modified authentication unique keys and salts. I made sure that there aren't any comment section inside by mistake. Everything seems clean.

The /** MySQL hostname */ is directing to 3.14.164.34 IP because I'm using an AWS server where I saved the database I'm trying to use for WordPress.

The 502 happens when I try to load the localhost page or the IP address  127.0.0.1 in a browser. I tested the remote connection of the database from the IP address 3.14.164.34 with DBeaver program and I verified that the remote connections in MySQL on the AWS server machine are successfully configured. The 502 response is immediate. The browser displays the 502 Error and the Nginx version that I'm using.

I just want to be able to display and install WordPress.

Comment: When does the 502 occur? You do not describe what you try and what you get, so it is a little difficult to help. 502 means "bad gateway", an intermediate server has dropped the connection prematurely (usually means: the operation on the server-side took too long, so the gateway assumed your process died)

Comment: This could be an AWS configuration issue. I tried that IP in a browser out of curiosity and it resolved to a WordPress setup page. I don't know enough about that environment to say for sure, but maybe they don't allow remote connections to the database. Have you tried connection with MySQL workbench or any other means?

Comment: My bad. I'm new at making questions, I apologize. 
The 501 happens when I try to load the localhost page or the IP 127.0.0.1 in a browser. 
I tested the remote conection of the database from the IP 3.14.164.34 with DBeaver program and I verifed that the remote conections in MySQL on the AWS server machine are succesfuly configured. 
The 502 response is immediate.The browser displays the 502 Error and the Nginx version that I'm using.

Comment: You need to look at the error log, which should describe the cause of the 5xx error.

Comment: This is a basic system administration problem, so you'd better ask on  [sf] or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)